# Threading in Forloop C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, asynchronous

I got a requirement where I need to process two Threads simultaneously in a ForLoop.

For Example :

```
private void BtnThreading_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(ProcessA);
        thread1.Start();

        thread1.Join();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(ProcessB);
        thread2.Start();
     }
}

private void ProcessA()
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}

private void ProcessB()
{
     Thread.Sleep(20000);
}
```

For the `First Time` in the `for-loop`,Let's say the `ProcessA()` takes `10 Seconds` to complete and I need to wait till the ProcessA() to finish using `thread1.Join();` to Start Processing `ProcessB()`.Later the ProcessB() starts and it will take 20 seconds to finish.

So,In the mean while `ProcessA()` again starts and `thread1.Join();` statement will wait until ProcessA() finishes.Here I need to wait also for the previous `ProcessB()` to finish.

so finally,**I want the `ProcessB()` to wait for the `Previous` Thread of `ProcessB()`**

Sorry for my Bad English !!! :)

Comment: Why are you creating a new thread for `ProcessA` at all if you need to immediately wait for it to finish? Just call it synchronously...

Comment: Have a look at the `Barrier` class.

Comment: And likewise, if you're then waiting for ProcessB to finish before starting the next ProcessA, it doesn't sound like *anything* is actually allowed to happen in parallel. Why are you using threads?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he wants B to work while A works, but then wait again until B finishes too before starting the "new" B. Still a bad design, but at least there's some benefit. So "new" A can run in parallel with "old" B.

Comment: Ah, I see - I'll add an answer, and see whether that's actually the intent.

Comment: @JonSkeet : yeah,I need to Run even ProcessA() while ProcessB() is running.So after fully finishing ProcessB(),again the ProcessB() need to start fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't really need `ProcessA` to execute in a different thread at all - but you *do* need to keep track of your previous ProcessB thread. So something like:

```
Thread previousThread = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    ProcessA();

    if (previousThread != null)
    {
        previousThread.Join();
    }

    previousThread = new Thread(ProcessB);
    previousThread.Start();
}
// Possibly join on previousThread here too
```

Note that your method name *suggests* that you're doing this in a UI thread - which you really, really shouldn't. Don't block the UI thread for any length of time - and remember that `Join` *is* a blocking call.

Comment: Can you suggest me a proper solution with out using Join?
I will try to change my requirement based on the solution.
This is the first time,I'm using MultiThreading :(

Comment: @RealSteel: Well we don't have enough context here. You might want to do *all* of this in a background thread, for example - you could still use a separate thread for ProcessB if you want, and still call `Join`, but you wouldn't be blocking the UI thread. You could also start looking into asynchrony, depending on what these processes are actually doing - that's a bit more complicated, but you should probably look into it at *some* point.

Comment: @Jon I think it will give error at  if (previousThread != null) as we are trying to access it before declaring previousThread..!!!!

Comment: @Jon Ops.. my bad.. ;(

Comment: @JonSkeet : Can you please give me a link where I can check the asynchrony and the right process to do this ?

Comment: @RealSteel: Well again, that's hard to do without knowing what you're trying to achieve. But http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh191443.aspx is probably a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your really need to do low level programming you should not use `Thread` objects directly. Each thread is quite expensive in terms of resources. Instead .NET provides several high level abstractions to do asynchronous and parallel programming. Your loop can be built using async and await and will then execute on thread pool threads. Here is an example:

Instead of using `Thread.Sleep` to simulate delay you have to use `Task.Delay`:

```
async Task ProcessA() {
  await Task.Delay(10000);
}

async Task ProcessB() {
  await Task.Delay(20000);
}
```

The loop:

```
var task = Task.Delay(0); // No operation task to simplify loop.
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) {
  await ProcessA();
  await task;
  task = ProcessB();
}
await task;
```

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion.Here I used Thread.Sleep only for explaning my Question.  
From now on,I start using asynchronous and parallel programming.

Comment: @RealSteel: This is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this code a try, but again it is not production ready..!!!

```
    Thread thread1 = null;
    Thread thread2 = null;
    private void BtnThreading_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            thread1 = new Thread(ProcessA);
            thread1.Start();

            thread1.Join();

            if (thread2 != null)
                thread2.Join();
            thread2 = new Thread(ProcessB);
            thread2.Start();
        }
    }
```